# Another div height not adjusting to content post

Tags: css, html, height

I've been reading the other posts from people having the same issue as I am but none of those solutions seem to be helping me. So, here's another post about my *.news-post* div height not adjusting to fit content inside of it. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="news-post">
        <div class="news-post-header">
            <a href="#"><h3>Fake News: blah blah blah.</h3></a><a href="#"><h3 style="float: right">July 26, 2013</h3></a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget tempor diam. Vivamus eget neque ultrices, accumsan risus et, laoreet dui. Curabitur eu ligula fermentum, molestie orci sit amet, molestie ante. Morbi id massa laoreet, pellentesque magna nec, ultrices dui. Nulla tempus est massa, in euismod velit congue eu. Curabitur ac congue dui. Curabitur id risus tempor, mattis odio vel, faucibus nisi. Nullam pretium, dolor id auctor hendrerit, metus lacus volutpat orci, sed dapibus lorem lacus non felis. Aliquam felis lorem, posuere nec fringilla eu, aliquam in ligula. Duis ultrices, ante in vestibulum sollicitudin, lectus mi tristique tellus, in volutpat est lorem nec mi.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#wrapper {
margin: auto auto;
width: 1024px;
}
.news-post {
background: #fff url('images/skydive.png') no-repeat;
margin: 30px 30px 0 0;
height: auto;
min-height: 100% !important;
width: 642px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
overflow: visible;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
-moz-box-shadow:    0 1px 3px 0 #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #ccc;
box-shadow:         0 1px 3px 0 #ccc;
}
.news-post-header {
background: url('images/content-header-bg.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
margin: 0;
height: 47px;
line-height: 40px;
width: 642px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
.news-post-header h3 {
margin: 0 15px;
font-family: 'droid_sansbold';
font-size: 14px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #626262;
color: #fff;
float: left;
}
.news-post-header p {
padding: 445px 15px 0 15px;
text-align: justify;
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Isn't it just because you set a `height: 47px` on your `.news-post-header` div? If that is not the problem, can you explain it a bit better?

Comment: lol! yeah, that fixed it. thanks! sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you set a `height` parameter to your `.news-post-header`.
If you remove that it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a fiddle of your code here. have a look and let me know if this is what you're looking for.

link: http://jsfiddle.net/daltonpereira/2ZXx9/

below is what i've changed. basically removed the height:47px from news-post-header class

```
.news-post-header {
 background: url('images/content-header-bg.png');
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 margin: 0;

line-height: 40px;
width: 642px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```